# Multiple files test with casperjs on mobile devices

Tags: unit-testing, casperjs

I'm trying to setup a test suite (multiple tests) with CasperJS and testing a interface on mobile devices (i.e. iPhone).
Unfortunately, as I see on casperjs documentation, cannot instantiate a create() method, but I'd need it to set the viewport and the userAgent.

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    // Set a mobile viewport
    viewportSize: {width: 480},
    pageSettings: {
        // Set a mobile useragent (iphone4)
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7'
    }
});
```

Any advice about how to overcome this?
Thank you in advance...
Teo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me for viewPortSize when I switched to using multiple files:

```
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1024, height: 768};
```

for userAgent try

```
casper.options.userAgent or 
casper.options.pageSettings.userAgent
```

You should probably create a separate file, like setup.js , put configuration there, and then run your tests with --includes=setup.js to ensure that all your tests will get the configuration you want.